# Existing Angular site with Wordpress as a front page

Tags: angular, wordpress, woocommerce

I couldn’t find any tutorial and I don’t know if it’s even possible. I have an Angular site that is just a front end for my Web Api backend. I want to set welcome page as „Pay for an access” and I want to do it with Wordpress with woocommerce. Is it possible to merge those two?

Summarizing
Existing Angular site with an access only after buying a subscription from Wordpress with Woocommerce site.

Comment: This is less of an Angular/Wordpress question as a question of your Authentication Service and your webserver setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by storing the user's information in a **shared database**.

1. You will need to implement an authentication system in your front end, specifically allowing users to login and view content only if they have certain permissions.

In order do check that you need to have a service that sends a request to your back-end and verifies whether the user exists or not (or whether it's a paid user or not).

2. Allow the users in Wordpress to pay and then write to the database the user details. Once that's done, the user would be able to login via your Angular website as the database will be shared.

You could use Firebase for example, a quick Google search showed me that you can store data [from Wordpress to Firebase](https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database/save-data-realtime-firestore.html), that pretty much gives you all you need.

Good luck!